# Object not going the direction I am throwing it even when using transform.forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I want to make the grenade the player is throwing go exactly where my camera is pointed, however, if I were to face my camera lower, the grenade doesn't get thrown directly forward, as seen in the video below:

https://streamable.com/dqjq4z

And here is the function for the grenade throwing:

```
private void Yeet()
    {
        GameObject grenade = Instantiate(wm_equipment, FPSCamera.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        grenade.GetComponent<Grenade>().delay = delay;
        Rigidbody rb = grenade.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        Vector3 forward = FPSCamera.transform.forward;

        rb.AddForce(forward * throwForce, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

I am using the forward vector of the the player's camera to tell which direction the grenade should be thrown. However it doesn't seem to be working in this case. Not sure what I've done wrong in this case, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible you spawn the grenade within your own player collider => the reason it flies away upwards is because it is being pushed out of the collider it spawns in ?

Comment: In general in this use case instead of using `AddForce` I would probably rather directly set `rb.velocity = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grenade's collider was indeed colliding with the player's collider, hence causing it to behave in that way.

Fixed by adding a forward offset to the spawning point:

```
GameObject grenade = Instantiate(
    wm_equipment,
    FPSCamera.transform.position + FPSCamera.transform.forward,  // <-----
    Quaternion.identity);
```

Thanks to everyone who answered this question

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will 100% work as its from the top of my head. Sorry if its not but maybe try:

```
Vector3 forward = transform.position + FPSCamera.transform.forward;
```

Comment: If not, do you have a collision box on the player and is the instantiation position inside of that when you look down. as that could potentially be what is causing that to happen?

Comment: yep that is what is causing it, thank you